# (Flutter/Dart) Two async methods in initState not working

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a `function` in my `initState`:

```
  @override
      void initState() {
       _fetchListItems();
        super.initState();
      }
```

This `function` is very simple. It has two `async` `await` operations of `sqflite`, one of which waits for the other to complete in it:

```
 _fetchListItems() async {
       wait() async {
         number = await db.getNumber(userId); }

       await wait();
     List rawFavouriteList = await db.getList(number);

      setState((){
      rawFavouriteList.forEach((item){
           _favouriteList.add(Model.map(item));
               }}); 
 }
```

I have to wait for `number` to be fetched, only then I can fetch serialized `List`, which then I deserialize and populate then add to the `List` which is displayed in `ListView`.

The problem is, this is not working in `initState`. It's working fine when it's called through `onPressed()` of a button, but not in `initState`.

**Points to Note:**

1) There is no error being thrown

2) I have already tried more conservative alternatives by using `await` for even `rawFavouriteList`through a separate function like `wait()` before using `setState()` top populate the `_favouriteList`, even though it's working fine manually through buttons.

3) Everything works fine if I manually enter `number` value in the second database query and just remove the first query, i.e.

```
_fetchListItems() async {
      List rawFavouriteList = await db.getList(42);
  setState((){
  rawFavouriteList.forEach((item){
       _favouriteList.add(Model.map(item));
           }}); 
  }
```

Comment: Four obvious issues: (1) initState() MUST begin with a call to super.initState(), (2) setState() inside initState is superfluous at best, (3) the function "wait()" serves no purpose, and (4) If you're calling an async function from within a synchronous one (like initState()), you should probably have a catch(),

Comment: ...and is "_faouriteList" a typo?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker No, rawFavouriteList is one which is serialized and _favouriteList is being displayed in ListView

Comment: So does it have a V or not?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "V". It's working just fine when I remove the first `wait()` function, and manually feed in value of `number`. Do you think its because 2 simultaneous await can't be handled in `initState`?

Also, i have implemented all the things you mentioned, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Should I use `FutureBuilder` instead of this?

Comment: Please see if I should use a FutureBuilder to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694731/flutter-listview-builder-using-futurebuilder-not-working

I am stuck even there :(

Comment: I have no idea what you *should* do, because I have no idea about your design or desired behavior. Can you not see the obvious missing V in "_faourite"? When I said the "wait" function serves no purpose, I assume you understood that the code inside it still needs to run (I assume) to get the number, which I assume is a class member. There's really not enough code here to guess further. If you can give us something more complete and a description of what the problem is ("it doesn't work" means nothing unless we know what it's supposed to do), we might be able to help.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker my bad. Yes it is a typo. Its `_favourite()` (I have updated the question). Also, the problem just is that the `list` is not being populated with the items fetched from `Sqflite` Database.

Comment: You haven't given us the code for db.getList(), so I don't know how you expect us to guess what's broken in it. You still don't have super.initState() at the start of your initState method,  When you give us complete code, we might be more helpful.