# (Flutter) ListView.builder using FutureBuilder not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display items in a `ListView` using `ListView.builder` inside a `FutureBuilder`. My `future` function for `FutureBuilder` looks like this:

```
_fetchListItems() async {
   wait() async {
     number = await db.getNumber(userId); }

   await wait();
 List rawFavouriteList = await db.getList(number);

  setState((){
  rawFavouriteList.forEach((item){
       _faouriteList.add(Model.map(item));
           }});
return _faouriteList;
}
```

My `FutureBuilder` looks like this:

```
            FutureBuilder(
               future: _fetchListItems(),
               builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                     if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         } else {Container( child: ListView.builder(                                                  
                itemCount: _faouriteList.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text(                                                 
                   '${_faouriteList[index].title}');
              }));}})
```

> he following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter (24728): _FutureBuilderState#f12a3):
>   I/flutter (24728): A build function returned null.
>   I/flutter (24728): The offending widget is: FutureBuilder
>   I/flutter (24728): Build functions must never return null
>
> Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null.

**Note:**

I tried to call `_fetchListItems()` from `initState` and not use `FutureBuilder` and that didn't work for me as well.

Here is a link to that case: [(Flutter/Dart) Two async methods in initState not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693883/flutter-dart-two-async-methods-in-initstate-not-working?noredirect=1#comment99953640_56693883)

Please let me know if I should use `FutureBuilder` or `initState` to wait for `List` to load it's data. And how to make it work since none of the methods seem to work for me :(

Comment: You can show your function `_bowlerIconFetch()` ?

Comment: @EdHuamani It was a typo. Its `_fetchListItems()` only. There is no `_bowlerIconFetch`. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your fetch `_fetchListItems` method is not the problem as far as I can tell.

Your error message is very clear, " a build function returned null". In this case, the method that returns null is the anonymous function passed as the builder argument to the `FutureBuilder`. You're just missing the `return` keyword inside the else case because you're just creating the instance of `Container` but not returning it.

Something like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _fetchListItems(),
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         } else {
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(                                                  
                    itemCount: _faouriteList.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text('${_faouriteList[index].title}');                                           
                    }
                )
            );
         }
     }
)
```

I don't know if there are any other problems with your code but this should solve the particular error message you are asking about.

Comment: This was such a silly mistake. I feel embarrassed. I would have gone haywire and wasn't going to find it anytime soon if you didn't point it out. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! happens to all of us.

Answer (score 9):

It is not necessary to use setState for your case, try this:

**Fetch async function**

```
  _fetchListItems() async {
    number = await db.getNumber(userId);
    List rawFavouriteList = await db.getList(number);
    List _faouriteList = rawFavouriteList.map((item)=>Model.map(item)).toList();
    return _faouriteList;
  }
```

**FutureBuilder**

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _fetchListItems(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text('${snapshot.data[index].title}');
              }));
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have removed `setState`

Comment: I wonder if something is wrong with using 
`rawFavouriteList.forEach((item){
       _faouriteList.add(Model.map(item));
      });`
that you have suggested instead
`_faouriteList = rawFavouriteList.map((item)=>Model.map(item)).toList();`

Comment: Also please consider answering this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715327/when-exactly-do-we-use-async-await-and-then

I believe you have good understanding of this based on your answer.