# When exactly do we use async-await and then?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very confused about this. I request you to clarify the concept.

Consider the following scenarios:

**Case 1:**

```
int number = 0; 

void calculate() {
   number = number + 2;
   print(number);
}
```

I know this works just fine. "2" will be printed on the terminal.

But why shouldn't I use `async`-`await` here, like this:

```
 int number = 0; 

void calculate() async {

 void addition() async {
   number = number + 2;
  }

 await addition();
   print(number);
}
```

This seems logical to me, since `print(number)` should wait for `number = number + 2` to finish. Why isn't this necessary? How does dart know which operation to execute first?

How is it ensured that `print(number)` isn't executed before `number = number + 2` and "0" is printed on the terminal?

```
Does the sequence in which we write these operations in the function matter?
```

**Case 2:**
Consider the case where I am interacting with `SQFLite` database and values fetched depend on each other.

**Note:** `number1`, `number2`, `number3` will still have values before the following `function` is called.

```
void getValues() async {

  void calculate1() {
   number1 = await db.getNumber1(10);
  }

  void calculate2() {
   number2 = await db.getNumber2(number1);
  }

  await calculate1().then((_) async {
    await calculate2().then((_) async {
     number3 = await db.getNumber3(number2);
    });
  });

}
```

I have a lot of these types of functions in my app and I am doing this everywhere.

I am kind of paranoid, thinking if old values of `number1`and `number2` are taken as a `parameter` in `getNumber2()` and `getNumber3()` respectively, then I'll be doomed.

Comment: See my answer, but just wanted to comment on "This seems logical to me, since print(number) should wait for number = number + 2 to finish. Why isn't this necessary? How does dart know which operation to execute first?".  "async" doesn't trigger creating a Future... it's just a flag that the body of the subroutine may contain an "await", which yours does not.

Answer (score 1):

`async`/`await` are just syntax sugar for the underlying `Future` framework.  95% of the time, they will suffice, and are preferred by the style guide.

One exception is that you may have multiple futures that you want to wait until all are complete *in parallel*. In that case, you'll need to use `Future.wait([future1, future2, future3])`, which cannot be expressed using `await`.

Comment: Can you please further clarify how is it ensured that the functions are executed in the desired order in the above cases, especially the 2nd case (Ofcourse if i don't write code like i have done in 2nd case, and just write a 3 line function:  `void getValues() async {
   number1 = await db.getNumber1(10);
   number2 = await db.getNumber2(number1);
     number3 = await db.getNumber3(number2);
}`     )

Comment: The await finishes the first Future before even launching the second Future.  There's not any "queue" of Futures at that point.

Comment: So it finishes the futures mentioned in the function in the sequence in which they are written?

Comment: BECAUSE you are using await.  That forces the future of interest to complete before continuing to the next statement.  Normally, futures fire in whatever order they complete, but you're not even launching the second future until the first one is done.

Answer (score 1):

Dart is executed line by line. So when the function is called calculation will be done first then it will be printed. So you will always get 2 printed

Answer (score 1):

You can see it like there is one main thread in general which is the UI thread. Any operations you are writing in this thread will be performed line by line and after completely executing one line it will move to next line.

Now suppose you have something which you know that it will take time to be computed or fully executed with either a result or error. If you will write this in the main UI thread (synchronous thread) that means you're stopping the UI of the app, which in turn makes the app to crash(Application Not Responding Error) as the operating system feels that the app has frozen but as you know this is happening because of the compute you are running in the UI thread which is taking time and the UI is waiting for it to be completely executed.

So to overcome this issue we use Asynchronous methods to compute the time taking computations like getting some data from a database which will return a value or error in "future". The main UI thread doesn't waits for the asynchronous threads. If you don't have anything to show to the user until any asynchronous task is completed you place the loading indicators for the time being.

Hope this helps!